# Localhost web page does not open in opera mini

Tags: jquery-mobile, opera, opera-mini

I have created site using jquery mobile. I have tested in mobile default browser and internet browser and its works fine. But whenever I will try to open in opera mini it gives connection error. Opera mini does not open my localhost site.

Any idea how to open localhost site in opera mini ?.

Answer (score 2):

Opera Mini is a thin client which is working with online proxy servers. So when you create a request in Opera Mini thin client, it sends it to the distant Opera servers. `localhost` has no meaning for the Opera servers or more exactly not the same meaning than your local machine. To test your page into Opera Mini, you have to host it on a place which is reachable through the Web.